# facebook's sharer.php shows 403 Forbidden in share box

Tags: django, facebook

I am using this for sharing on Facebook.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://url.com/{{ article.img_path }}">
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ article.title }}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ article.title }}"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://url.com/{{ article.path }}"/>
.
.
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://url.com/{{ article.path | urlencode }}">
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

1. I also get a 403 Forbidden in the box.
2. Default is mobile view even on Desktop ?

[image]

Comment: _"I also get a 403 Forbidden in the box."_ - then you need to go figure out why _your_ site responded with a 403, when the Facebook scraper tried to fetch the meta data.

Comment: Do we need to register the website at Facebook's app program ?

Comment: No, not for merely sharing. Your site responded with a 403 when the scraper tried to request the meta data, so you need to find out, why. Probably some sort of firewalling that tries to block "bots" from accessing the site.